# Is it posible to make the NDK compiler ignore specific cpp files through code inside them?

Tags: android-ndk, cross-compiling

First of all I must say I'm new to Android NDK development.

I'm trying to compile a working engine (openGL and openCL based) with the NDK to use it in Android.

I have variables in the headers and cpp files defined to separate the OpenGL 3.0 code and the OpenGLES 2.0 one.

Anyways, in the Android.mk file I recursively add all the .cpp files in the folders and subfolders when compiling so no code differentiation is performed and the compilation fails.

How can I work around this?

(I'm using Eclipse Luna CDT + ADT in MAC OSX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is done via the Android.mk file adding the flags:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK
```

This defines the MACRO "ANDROID_NDK"

Then in the code use:

```
#ifdef ANDROID_NDK
...
```

and so on.